# Generate link to relevant line of source code

Tags: doxygen

I have documented my code with doxygen. The generated docs consist of:

- a page with the documentation as I put between `/** ... */`, and
- a page with the source-code itself (without the documentation between `/** ... */`).

Now my question is: Is there a way to generate links such that one can reach the page with the source code opened on the relevant line directly from the documentation?

---

To show visually what I would like to obtain:

1. I would like to have a button "Go to source" (shown in red, decorated with an arrow just for here).

   [image]
2. Which would land me on the right line of the source code (possibly with a highlight, as shown here).

   [image]

Comment: The question is a bit unclear and it would have been better that you would have added a small example and mentioned which version you used. The question is to what type of entities do you want to link in the source code? At the moment there are, to the best of my knowledge, no possibilities to do this.

Comment: @albert Thank you for the comment. I have edited in an attempt to make things clearer. Do you agree that that is the case?

Comment: The only way and also with the assumption you are only using HTML output would be to use a HTML link to the mentioned line as each line in the source code has a name like `<a name="l00012">`, though this is very error prone as when the source code changes the line number can change and thus the link will be to another place. This accounts for a specific line, but when you would enable `SOURCE_BROWSER=YES` (and maybe `STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS=NO`) you will get with a link in the detailed description to the source code. Also have a look at the `\snippet` command and the setting for `INLINE_SOURCES`.

Comment: @albert Thanks! Indeed, that is a error prone and labour intensive work-around. I was indeed hoping for an option of doxygen that I did not manage to find. I will file an issue

Comment: For reference: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/8385

Answer (score 0):

The following option does exactly that:

```
SOURCE_BROWSER = YES
```

Thanks @albert!